# How to create a function of N exponentials in python to fit data

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to write a code in python that fit a sum of exponetials to some data. However I want to have the freedom to choose how many exponetials I use.

```
def fcn(x,nexp):
    return sum(ai * np.exp(-Ei * x)  for ai, Ei in range(nexp))
```

I have tried to define the above and then call it inside scipy.optimize.curve_fit but I get the error "'int' object is not iterable". Any help would greatly be appreciated. At the moment I just keep defining new functions and adding terms as follow

```
def f1(t,a1,E1):
    return a1*np.exp(-E1*t)


def f2(t,a1,E1,a2,E2):
    return a1*np.exp(-E1*t)+a2*np.exp(-E2*t)


def f3(t,a1,E1,a2,E2,a3,E3):
    return a1*np.exp(-E1*t)+a2*np.exp(-E2*t)+a3*np.exp(-E3*t)


def f4(t,a1,E1,a2,E2,a3,E3,a4,E4):
    return a1*np.exp(-E1*t)+a2*np.exp(-E2*t)+a3*np.exp(-E3*t)+a4*np.exp(-E3*t)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing each `a1, E1` as separate arguments, you could have one function that accepts a list of two-tuples (e.g. `[(a1,E1),(a2,E2)]`)then iterate through.

`def f(t, lst):
    sum = 0
    for a, E in lst:
        sum += a*np.exp(-E*t)
    return sum`

This could be written shorter, I gave it step-by-step for clarity.

Comment: the one-liner would be `return sum([a*np.exp(-E*t) for a,E in lst])`

Comment: Using lambda function will be a much better approach!

    `f = lambda t, lst: sum(a * np.exp(-E * t) for a in lst for E in lst)

    f(a1,E1)`

just check the occurrence of a and E as then it will be all the pairs in this case

Comment: that's a better one liner, but using lambda like that is generally frowned upon in python

Comment: @JasonStein in your case it may give error for the following: {for a,E in lst}.
They should be in separate for loop like {for a in lst for E in lst} or in other way if you want lesser pairs.